# android.mk arm-linux-androideabi-g++ exceptions and __cxa_allocate_exception

Tags: android, exception

I am rebuilding Android from source (to flash onto a device, right now using emulator), trying to add a single command line tool. I've put my source in repo/exernal/... and written `Android.mk`.

I get the following undefines:

```
__cxa_allocate_exception
__cxa_begin_catch
__cxa_end_catch
__cxa_end_cleanup
__cxa_free_exception
__cxa_get_exception_ptr
__cxa_rethrow
__cxa_throw
__gxx_personality_v0
```

I've searched through the other issues here with the same undefines, but can't quite seem to find the solution for Android.

The final link command gets generated as:

```
prebuilt/darwin-x86/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.x/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -nostdlib -Bdynamic -Wl,-T,build/core/armelf.x -Wl,-dynamic-linker,/system/bin/linker -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,nocopyreloc -o out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/wavsender_intermediates/LINKED/wavsender -Lout/target/product/generic/obj/lib -Wl,-rpath-link=out/target/product/generic/obj/lib -lc -llog -lcutils -lnetutils -lc -lstdc++ -lm  out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o    out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/wavsender_intermediates/ohSongcast/WavSender/WavSender.o              out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/liblog_intermediates/liblog.a out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libcutils_intermediates/libcutils.a out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libopenhome_intermediates/libopenhome.a out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libgtest_intermediates/libgtest.a out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libstlport_static_intermediates/libstlport_static.a out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libstdc++_intermediates/libstdc++.a out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libgabi++_intermediates/libgabi++.a   -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,--icf=safe -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 prebuilt/darwin-x86/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.x/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/armv7-a/libgcc.a out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/crtend_android.o
```

Android.mk is:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := wavsender
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := eng
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fexceptions -D_GNU_SOURCE -DPLATFORM_ANDROID
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += WavSender.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libc libcutils libnetutils
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libcutils libopenhome
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libopenhome libgtest libstlport_static libstdc++ libgabi++
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lstdc++
include external/stlport/libstlport.mk
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Can anyone see a problem or point me in a direction to get the correct behavior from arm-linux-androideabi-g++ ?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Try running make with 'showcommands' to get the detailed compile lines. In mine I see my '-fexceptions' but _also_ '-fno-exceptions' which is the default. I wonder which takes precedence or even if this has anything to do with the linkage problem. Probably not.

Answer (score 1):

Consider removing libstd++ as a static in Android.mk it should default to the standard Android implementation and you should be fine

Actually, I see you added it both as a static and dynamic libraries.

Remove either static libstdc++ or the dynamic one. If that doesn't do it try removing both

Answer (score 0):

All your undefines are from libstdc++.

It often happens when you have differents libstdc++ versions and compile with a certain version and link with another, or forget to link.

Sometimes, it can even happend if the link is done after a library which needs it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar __cxa undefines awhile back as a result of building a project that was pulling in libraries/shared objects where some defined APP_STL := gnustl_shared while others declared gnustl_static in their Application.mk files.

Perhaps you might be running into something similar?  If so, I'd recommend using one or the other in the combined solution, but not both.